# Check that the text contains a string

Tags: c#, string

I have a list of strings that I check to see if they contain certain text, now I have a problem with this string which looks like this:

```
00:43:00\nExampleText
```

Now i want to find that text, something like this

```
if (cevent.EventText.Contains("ExampleText ") || cevent.EventText == "nExampleText2"){

}
```

Of course this doesn't work with `Contains`, how else could I handle this?

Something like Likes: `%nExampleText%` ?

Comment: I'm sorry what exactly is the question?

Comment: The question is pretty clear, Mara would like to check a string on "ErrorText". But can you please give a bit more context is cevent a list? If so is it a list of plain strings?

Comment: What do you mean "Of course this doesn't work", exactly? What goes wrong? Do you get some kind of error? In theory, if `cevent.EventText` is a string which holds the text you've shown, then it should work correctly. Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uMfCOF . If that is not the case for you, then there is something important you are not telling us. Please clarify the exact nature of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Seppe i just want to check if the string contains "errortext"

Comment: @Mara I think you have not understood Seppe's question. I am asking you something similar. We cannot help you more unless you provide extra information as we have requested.

Comment: @ADyson I have no error, error should occur, this is an example only, I just want a simple solution to compare whether the string is LIKE '% example_text%'

Comment: `cevent.EventText.Contains("ExampleText ")`should work as you expect, but be aware that at least in your example you have a tailing blank in your text. This will be part of the comparison. Try `cevent.EventText.Contains("ExampleText")`

Comment: @Mara `LIKE '% example_text%'` would fail (if this was SQL) because your string does not contain a space. Here's the .NET equivalent using Contains:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/FxRqJY . Notice how the one where we test for `" ExampleText"` fails because of the space. But the C# code you've posted doesn't suffer from that problem, so it's unclear why you would still be having an issue.

Comment: @Mara P.S. in your revised code, `if (cevent.EventText.Contains("ExampleText ") || cevent.EventText == "nExampleText2"){` can be shortened simply to `if (cevent.EventText.Contains("ExampleText ")) {`. The second one will never be true, because the `n` is not a separate character, it's part of `\n` which is a special character denoting a newline. Also, you're already asking if the text _contains_ "ExampleText", so that'll be true even before it tries to test the second condition, so it's redundant anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this worked pretty good in my case. Please correct me, if the input is different:

```
    static bool Check(string s)
    {
        return s.Contains("ErrorText");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool b = Check("00:43:00\nErrorText ");
    }
```

edit:
Ok, I think I got you. What you may want to check are regular expressions (`class Regex`). You can then check if the passed string has a certain format.

Comment: yes this is one of the solutions to my problem, thank you. is there another simpler solution not to use the extra method?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "use the extra method"?

Comment: this is ok too, so I thought if # has another solution already, that I don't have to go through your method every time I check the text Check

Comment: @Mara you don't have to wrap it in the "Check" method if you don't want to...you can just call .Contains directly if you like. Other than allowing you to repeatedly search for the same text without re-writing it, it has no extra benefit

Answer (score 0):

You have an error. To compare strings in the second condition, you should use the .Equals method, not a '=='. Maybe your error came from here.